# How do I right align links in the navigation bar of my Vue.js project?

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-material

I want to right align my product and support links in my navigation bar. How do you align links in the navigation bar of a [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) project overall?

[This is how it looks now](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m073hp/41/)

This is the code.

```
<md-whiteframe class = "main-toolbar  ">

  <md-theme name = "teal">

      <md-toolbar  class = "">

     <router-link class = "nav-link " :to = " { name: 'levi' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none; ">levi</router-link>

          <router-link id = "nav"class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Product' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none;">
        Product
    </router-link> 

     <router-link id = "nav" class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Support' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none;">
        Support
    </router-link>


      </md-toolbar>

  </md-theme>

   </md-whiteframe>
```

Comment: You've asked 21 questions to date and never accepted an answer for any of them. You should participate in the site! Give people feedback when they answer your questions with upvotes and accepts.

Comment: @BertEvans I am sorry for not participating enough. I will increase my conribution to the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex:1` to the style of your `levi` link.

```
<md-toolbar  class = "">
  <router-link class = "nav-link " :to = " { name: 'levi' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none; flex: 1">levi</router-link>
  <router-link id = "nav"class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Product' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none;">
    Product
  </router-link> 
  <router-link id = "nav" class = "nav-link" :to = "{ name: 'Support' }" style = "color:white; text-decoration: none;">
    Support
  </router-link>
</md-toolbar>
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3m073hp/43/).